# Get the real screen size of android devices

Tags: android, size, compatibility

I would like to use screen width/height as a basis to handle "size" issues in different devices.

I tried the following code, however, it can only get the "resolution" but not "screen size".

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics= getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
```

For example, my 7" tablet returns 600 width and my 4.3" phone returns 540 width.
It's unreasonable since tablet's size is almost a double of phone.

How can I get the real size under human vision or I should go for other approach to handle size issue?

Comment: Why do you say it's unreasonable? Your tablet has probably a resolution of 1024*600 and your phone has probably a resolution of 960*540. Very typical for both. Please google for your devices specs and you'll see.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It's unreasonable to me is because I am looking for a value to describe the the size under "human vision" but not "resolution". And that's why I create this question:)

Comment: And note that resolution has nothing to do with dpi. Your phone is probably an hdpi one and your tablet an mdpi one

Comment: Yes, there's nothing wrong in the resolutions obtained, but I would say it's not what I'm looking for. So is there a better way to scale size properly in my case?

Comment: Your best bet is to make several drawable folders and put in each a different version of your graphics, Android will choose the proper folder from which to take the pictures.